# How to use Radio button in menu to change text and background colour of a textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button

basically I am trying to create a night mode of white text on black background on radio button click. I would like the radio button to be gray when not clicked and green when clicked/active. I have been able to make the item toast on click but lost from here. I have attached a screenshot below. No idea what to do next. Thanks for your help.

[Night mode gray image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXaIK.png)

Code in Activity

```
enter code here @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_text, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        if (id == R.id.item2) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Night mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.item3) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fonts", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.font1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Font 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.font2) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Font 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.font3) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Font 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


Menu xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>

            <item android:id="@+id/item2"
                android:title="@string/night_mode"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_night"
                app:showAsAction="withText" />

            <item android:id="@+id/item3"
                android:title="@string/font"
                app:showAsAction="never" >

                <menu>

                    <item android:id="@+id/font1"
                        android:title="Times Roman"/>

                    <item android:id="@+id/font2"
                        android:title="Vollkorn"/>

                    <item android:id="@+id/font3"
                        android:title="Default"/>

                </menu>

            </item>


        </menu>


    </item>


</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE)` where MODE stands for one of these scenarios:

- AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
- AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
- AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO

For your project, you will need to switch between `MODE_NIGHT_NO` and `MODE_NIGHT_YES` because `MODE_NIGHT_AUTO` will change the App Theme depending on the time.

When you hit the radio button you have to switch the mode and recreate the activity, calling `activity.recreate()`

For more information, there is a useful article here: [DayNight Theme Android Tutorial with Example](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/daynight-theme-android-tutorial-example/)